# how to change android activity in tab dynamically

Tags: android

I have two similar question,

1.
I have a TabActivity, and when I select one specific tab I want to display one of two candidates activities. And it depends on run-time. i.e. I want to display two different activity in one tab dynamically due to different mode.

For more detail description,
It's like a social platform, user may belong to a group or not.
If he belongs to a group, when he select "GroupTab", he can see a activity page for group info.

If he does not belong to any group, when he select "GroupTab", he can see a list of all available groups.

He can join or quit a group dynamically, so the GroupTab's content is depend on run-time.

2.
When I press a button in a activity (which is in a Tab), I want to change to next activity, and that activity could go backward to original activity too. (All activities should be under the Tab)

--

I've seen some method using ActivityGroup, and since it is deprecated, I'm looking for some other alternative way to implement that.
Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: For your first question. I'm thiking that you can use the OnTabChangeListener and then check what tab is currently selected and based on that check if a user belongs to a group or not.

For question two, Fragment is the way to go. There's a post on it here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html

EDIT: You will have to install the compatibility package to use Fragments in Android < 3.0

Comment: second thing i want to implement is more like a navigator in Tab just like iOS does.

Comment: Sadly I don't know much about iOS, so I might not really be able to help on that one. I hope my answer to your second question is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you Nicholas, I'm still studying Fragment, but it seems not what i want because I'm writing app on Android phone instead of tablet. It's very close to what I was looking for though. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Fragment is what you need. "This class is deprecated.
Use the new Fragment and FragmentManager APIs instead; these are also available on older platforms through the Android compatibility package." taken from: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html. - Hopefully you will figure it out, see my updated answer ;-)

Comment: OK, i'll study deeper. But it may be helpful for the 2nd question not for the 1st one. I've updated my question description, hope it's more clear now. Thank you again.

Comment: I updated my answer to help you with your first question aswell.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't make my point clear. It's always the same Grouptab, only the content in that tab need to change dynamically depends on user's status. i.e. One tab(container) to multiple content.

Comment: I can't use fragment for my android 2.3.3 device

Comment: Remember to install the compatability package. A guide to do so can be found here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html